# Nesting Echo's or output variable differently?

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, custom-fields

I am trying to check to make sure a custom-field is not blank before echoing the custom-field.

This is what I have

```
<?php 
  $key = 'one_line_summary'; 
  $themeta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE); 
  if($themeta != '') {
    echo '<blockquote><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, one_line_summary, true); ?></blockquote>';
  }
?>
```

But it out puts the "get_post_meta($post->ID, one_line_summary, true);" literally rather than the contents of the variable one_line_summary.

I am a beginner but I feel like I need to either use nested echo's somehow or change the second echo all together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested `<?php ?>` inside an existing set of PHP tags, which is not allowed.  Remove those, and concatenate in the function call to `get_post_meta()`.  What happened here is that the inner `<?php ?>` tags were output as strings to the browser, but not rendered onscreen (since the browser treated them as unknown HTML tags).

```
echo '<blockquote>' .  get_post_meta($post->ID, one_line_summary, true) . '</blockquote>';
```

As a note, these kinds of issues are considerably easier to spot with proper code indentation as was done when your post was edited above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. This fixed it. I'll work on my indentation.

Comment: More along the lines of nesting PHP code inside a string, which means it's not php code. it's just text that LOOKS like php code.